# onclick with change javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, onchange

I have some questions about onclick and change. Can you explain me what shall I do with my code to print one of my onclick instead of summing up one by one when i would like to click on each of my div. I mean i would like to have only 1 green(on the image) tile and changing instead of summing up.

```
for(let i=0; i<woeid.length; i++){
 $( ".aClick"+i ).click(function() {
  $( "#aClick"+i ).toggle( "slow", function(){
  });
 });
};
```

html div click

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
 <div  id="backgroundImage0" class="inner-container aClick0">
  <p id="weather0"></p><img id="image0">
 </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-2">
 <div  id="backgroundImage1" class="inner-container aClick1"><p 
  id="weather1"></p><img id="image1">
 </div>
</div>
```

That green ties

```
 <div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="inner-container moreWeather afterClick"id="aClick0">
   <p id="nWeather0"></p>
  </div>
 </div>

<div class="col-md-2">
 <div class="inner-container moreWeather afterClick"id="aClick1">
  <p id="nWeather1"></p>
 </div>
</div>
```

[3 clicks on 3 different divs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCZqO.jpg)

That was 3 different Cities click on div. Is it possible to do only one instead of 2 or more displays.

Comment: A few lines of HTML would better help answer this question. 
From the looks of it your html could be modified to make what you're doing much simpler. I can tell you now that if you're using your html classes correctly then that for loop wouldn't be necessary to do this.

Comment: I would suggest including all relevant code and producing a Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  No where in the code provided are you summing anything.

Comment: You are right iam not summing anything. Maybe my question was wrong. My problem is that I would like to have only 1 green tie all the time no matter what I do. I mean when I click on Warsaw program will print 5 next weather days for only Warsaw but when i will klick on Warsaw then Paris then only Paris for next 5 days etc. instead od that it print right now Warsaw and Paris next to each other. You can see that on that image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see to options that might help:

Use the startWith selector and then parse your class name as

```
$('[class^=aClick]')
```

or use a generic aClick class, with a data-target attribute to tell which one of the divs you want to toggle. Your code would become something like:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <div  id="backgroundImage0" class="inner-container aClick" data-target="aClick0">
        <p id="weather0"></p><img id="image0">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <div  id="backgroundImage1" class="inner-container aClick" data-target="aClick1"><p id="weather1"></p><img id="image1">
    </div>
</div>
```

Your jQuery code would look like this:

```
$(".aClick").click(function() {
  var targetDiv = $(this).data("target");
  $('[id^="aClick"]:not([id="' + targetDiv + '"])').hide('slow');
  if (!$('#' + targetDiv).is('visible')) {
    $('#' + targetDiv).show('slow');
  }
});
```

jdfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wqnhs6dy/4/

Edit: Apologies for misunderstanding the question, I modified the script to actually hide the other divs when clicking the target one, using the jquery selectors startsWith ( ^= ) and :not() together

Comment: I mean You can have 2 red ties. I need to have only one. When i click on _weather0_ it prints **moreWeather0**, but if I click _weather0_ then _weather1_ the **moreWeather0** form weather1 will change into **moreWeather1** instead of 2 of them.

Comment: Right, I got it wrong first, but I just updated my answer with a solution that hides the other divs an shows just the one you want to. This should be a decent groundwork to implement your own solution hopefully.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is working right now correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I generally do this with a combination of CSS classes and jQuery

```
$("div[class^='aClick']").click(function(e){
    //remove all the visible green stuff
    $(".moreWeather.afterClick").removeClass("afterClick");
    //add the one back you want, you can use $(this) to reference the DIV you clicked.
});
```

You can animate the addition or removal of the css class if you choose, but in its simplest form and without additional information this is the best direction I can point you in.